# Convert row to columns

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck with a problem in SQL Server.

My query is like this:

```
select Format(new_qtrdate1,'dd-MMM') as MTBURDATE1,
       Format(new_qtrdate2,'dd-MMM') as MTBURDATE2,
       Format(new_qtrdate3,'dd-MMM') as MTBURDATE3,
       new_mtbur1 as MTBUR1,
       new_mtbur2 as MTBUR2,
       new_mtbur3 as MTBUR3
  from Filterednew_craform
 where
```

The current result of my query looks like this:

```
(MTBURDATE1) (MTBURDATE2) (MTBURDATE3) MTBUR1 MTBUR2 MTBUR3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
01-May         01-Jun        01-Jul    34214  10756   9879
```

What I want to get is this:

```
Date    MTBUR
------------
01-May  34214
01-Jun  10756
01-Jul  9879
```

How can I do that?

Comment: whats your query?

Comment: do you want to Change the table in your Server, or do you just Need SQL to achieve that Output?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem? You can find many similar questions here is SO addressing the exact same issue,

Comment: i dont want to change anything in the table,i want SQL to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have fixed number of columns try below:

```
with CTE as
(
    SELECT....... -- Your Query
)

Select MTBURDATE1 AS Date, MTBUR1 AS MTBUR from CTE
UNION ALL
Select MTBURDATE2, MTBUR2 from CTE
UNION ALL
Select MTBURDATE3, MTBUR3 from CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is `UNION ALL` should do what you Need:

```
SELECT (MTBURDATE1)
       , MTBUR1 
  FROM Filterednew_cra
 UNION ALL
SELECT (MTBURDATE2)
       , MTBUR2 
  FROM Filterednew_cra
 UNION ALL
SELECT (MTBURDATE3)
       , MTBUR3 
  FROM Filterednew_cra
```

Comment: all the fields are from same table

Comment: My Query is like this :-                                                                        
select Format(new_qtrdate1,'dd-MMM') as MTBURDATE1,Format(new_qtrdate2,'dd-MMM') as MTBURDATE2,Format(new_qtrdate3,'dd-MMM') as MTBURDATE3,
new_mtbur1 as MTBUR1,new_mtbur2 as MTBUR2,new_mtbur3 as MTBUR3
from Filterednew_craform
where